# Magento 1.9 - How to apply shopping cart price rule for Total Weight?

Tags: free-shipping, magento1.9.2.3

Condition: Actually I have applied free shipping, and I need to add a condition like if total weight equal or greater than 10 not apply free shipping.

My workout:

https://snag.gy/Ttsyx6.jpg

Condition not working.

Comment: You mean not to show a shipping method called as "Freeshipping" when condition is not met?

Comment: No, still showing free shipping, I need should be show my courier service instead of free shipping.

Comment: Ok so this is what i have understood. You have lets say 4 shipping methods(including freeshipping & carriers). Your customer can see all 4 of those in case of total weight less than 10. But in case if total weight is greater than 10, your customer should only see 3 of those (excluding free shipping one). Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: No, my default free shipping condition is, if order above 1000 customer get free shipping, this condition working good, here I need one extra condition if cart weight equal or greater than 10kg the free shipping condition not showing to customer. Here the amount based condition should be overright.